# Poland to south korea

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have a multiple D visa from Poland (Europe), I plan to visit South Korea for one week of vacation.  I need a visa to enter South Korea or can I go through a transit visa?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your nationality (i.e. which country's passport do you carry)? That will be the most important detail as to whether you must obtain a visitor visa for South Korea or not. More or less by definition, a transit visa can only be used if the primary purpose of your entry to a country is for onward transit, but it is not clear whether that is what you intended to mean.